# how to access to widgets of a View in Android?

Tags: java, android, view

I'm making a `View` by inflating an xml layout:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(com.example.R.layout.aaa, null);
```

in aaa.xml I have a `RelativeLayout` that itself includes a `TextView` and a `Button`. now how can I access to that `TextView` on view object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the TextView you are trying to reach must have an id (e.g. @android:id="@+id/yourTxtId"), and then from your rootView, in your case the View you are actually inflating all you have to do is:

```
View view=inflater.inflate(com.example.R.layout.aaa, null);
TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTxtId);
//And here you have the reference...
```

Regards!

Comment: If you mark it as correct would increase your acceptance ratio, so in future people might take time to answer your questions...